# Route Similarity Percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My brother and I have similar routes to work, so similar in fact he claimed that they were 99% similar. That would make sense to me if we both drove 100 miles and only the last mile of each commute diverged. However, this is not the case.

The first 30.3 miles of our commutes are the same. I then drive 3.3 miles to get to work and my brother drives 8.2 miles to get to work. How similar (in percentage) are our commutes?

For me this would be a lot easier if both commutes were the same length. How do I go about computing similarity of things which are not equal like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Percentages are often ambiguous because what's not made clear is what they are percentages *of*.  The amount of your route which is on your brother's route is $\frac{30.3}{30.3+3.3}$ *of your route* and also it is $\frac{30.3}{30.3+8.2}$ of your brother's route.

Answer (score 2):

[Jaccard similarity coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index) and the derived Jaccard distance is one among many possible ways to quantify similarity and can be used here even though it's primarily used on binary features (in pattern recognition).

Building on oks's answer, the Jaccard similarity between your route and your brother's is:

$\frac{30.3}{30.3+3.3+8.2}=0.72488$ (this is *not* in units of percentage)

30.3 is in the numerator because it's the length of the intersection of your routes, while the denominator is the length of the (Y-shaped) union of your routes.